# styling the contents

Tags: content

I am newbie to wordpress and just started to play with themes. My problem is I want to  change the css of the content part and for that I want to know by default the content comes in the blog page comes from which page. I made echo from many pages but not got any result. Can any one tell me all the contents comes from which page?

Answer (score 2):

I'll refer you to the excellent [template hierarchy diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), which explains how template files are chosen:

[image: WordPress template hierarchy]

That explains the "which page" aspect of your question, but you also mentioned modifying CSS based on content. The [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/body_class) function should be a part of your template, and it will apply a number of classes to the `<body>` tag which allow you to target CSS at specific types of content. For example, given a category "spooky," this CSS rule would give all "spooky" pages a black background:

```
.category-spooky { background-color: #000; }
```

Many other variations exist, for other types of targeting.